# Layouts in android - how to make 3 columns?

Tags: android, layout

Im trying to create something like this (colors are only for better understanding, background will be white):

[image]

**My problem is 3 boxes containing two TextViews, one under another.**

This is my code so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <!-- row 1 -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView0"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:background="#3366ff"/>
    <!-- row 1 end -->

    <!-- row 2 -->

        <!-- col 1 -->
            <TextView
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView1"
                android:background="#aaaaaa"
                />

            <TextView
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView1A"
                android:background="#cccccc"
                />
        <!-- col 1 end -->

        <!-- col 2 -->
            <TextView
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView2"
                android:background="#bbbbbb"
                />

            <TextView
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView2A"
                android:background="#dddddd"
                />

        <!-- col 2 end -->

        <!-- col 3 -->
            <TextView
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView3"
                android:background="#cccccc"
                />

            <TextView
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView3A"
                android:background="#eeeeee"
                />
        <!-- col 3 end -->

    <!-- row 2 end -->

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is result of my incomplete code:

[image]

I was experimenting with `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout`. I totally don't understand last one.

Comment: You should use another layout inside the root layout

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try something like this:

Put the two textviews of each column under a LinearLayout (Vertical) and finally put the three LinearLayouts under a Horizontal LinearLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- row 1 -->

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#3366ff"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="TextView0"
        android:textSize="24dp" />
    <!-- row 1 end -->


    <!-- row 2 -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <!-- col 1 -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#aaaaaa"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="TextView1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#cccccc"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="TextView1A" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- col 1 end -->
        <!-- col 2 -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#bbbbbb"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="TextView2" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#dddddd"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="TextView2A" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- col 2 end -->
        <!-- col 3 -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#cccccc"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="TextView3" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#eeeeee"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="TextView3A" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- col 3 end -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Use weight for equal wightage of all three column linear layouts.

Screenshot:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh dear, I thought `android:orientation` is for screen orientation! It works. Thanks!

Comment: I allowed myself to resize your screenshot to 50% because it was TOO BIG :)

Comment: Cool :) @Kamil no prob.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put 3 TextView in some Layout

and if you want to let 3 TextView to have exact same width you might need to set their weight

something like this

```
<!-- row 2 -->
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <!-- col 1 -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <TextView
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView1"
            android:background="#aaaaaa"
            />

        <TextView
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView1A"
            android:background="#cccccc"
            />
    <!-- col 1 end -->
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <!-- col 2 -->
        <TextView
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView2"
            android:background="#bbbbbb"
            />

        <TextView
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView2A"
            android:background="#dddddd"
            />

    <!-- col 2 end -->

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <!-- col 3 -->
        <TextView
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView3"
            android:background="#cccccc"
            />

        <TextView
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView3A"
            android:background="#eeeeee"
            />
    <!-- col 3 end -->

    </LinearLayout>
<!-- row 2 end -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

We need to use nested layout
The layout should be somewhat like this

```
       <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
             <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Very clean answer, but why you put `0dp` there?

Comment: ok. android:layout_weight attribute holds the ratio value of how to share the space between its sister components. In our case it is the three textviews. If you set height= 0. then we will get a vertical stack of objects. If we set width =0, we will get horizontal stack.     Which ever you set to 0dp, android uses the weight attribute values and splits the layout

Answer (score 0):

Change the orientation of your LinearLayout to place the views horisontally:

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

But it will break when there is no more space as the views will not go to the next line automatically.

To create exactly what is on the picture try something like

```
<LinearLayout>
<!--horizontal-->
   <LinearLayout>
   <!--vertical-->
      <TextView />
      <TextView />
   </LinearLayout>
   <!-- repeat while you need -->
</LinearLayout>
```

But do you really need the TextViews? On a picture, it looks like the tabs...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a horizontal LinearLayout which has three sublayouts which are vertical (RelativeLayouts are also possible but i stick to LinearLayouts because you dint fully understand RelativeLayouts). Every of the three sublayouts contains the two textviews of the column. I have implemented it below for one column, just copy paste the layout for the first column.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

<!-- row 1 -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView0"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:background="#3366ff"/>
<!-- row 1 end -->

<!-- row 2 -->
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<!-- col 1 -->
        <TextView
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView1"
            android:background="#aaaaaa"
            />

        <TextView
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView1A"
            android:background="#cccccc"
            />
    <!-- col 1 end -->
    </LinearLayout>

<!-- row 2 end -->
</LinearLayout>
```